# Why reputation suddenly dropped from 900 to 282 without any reason?

Tags: support, reputation

Two days back my reputation dropped to 282 from 900 without no reason.No down votes or any such similar issues.
What was the problem?
Was it a technical fault?What should I do now?

Somebody out here from moderators to help?

Comment: As a side note you can [associate your account](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) here on meta with your StackOverflow account and get 100 rep bonus on each site.

Comment: Looks like your standard penalty cheque.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One possibility is that there is a background function that attempts to find [suspicious voting patterns](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you?referer=sphere_search), and undoes them, which can result in a dramatic change in reputation for some users. In some cases this is because a user has setup a shell account to upvote everything they do. However, sometimes it is simply because someone decided to follow everything you do and upvote it, which at some point the algorithm may detect and undo the upvotes.

Comment: That is just awesome.Still I don't know why my reputation was calculated?

Comment: email team@stackoverflow.com for more information

Comment: A recalc goes hand-in-hand with the suspicious voting patterns.

Answer (score 12):

If any of your questions or answers were either deleted or migrated to another site, the Rep you earned from them will be removed when a Rep recalculation is done.

Comment: this is a big, non-obvious and innocent explanation - albeit massively irritating and unfair :)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer (with a drop of rep that significant) is that your reputation was recalculated, for whatever reason.

Comment: But why and how come?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. Like @yshuditelu pointed out, there's a background function that checks for suspicious activity; you might have set it off for some reason. As to **specifically** why, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, looking at your history of questions, I notice you had a bounty on some of them, and accepted answers on them two days ago.  You also edited someone else's question, and answered it, gaining a bounty from *that*.  It's all that activity in a short time period from someone fairly low on reputation to begin with that probably looks suspicious to the automated checkers.